# WPF - ListView Pass Selected Row In and Out of User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am making a user control to be placed in a SCADA application. I am exposing a RowSelection property. When the RowSelection property is changed, I update the selected index in my listview (this works). But I also want to update the property when the selected row is changed by the user clicking in the listview. My event is firing but the property is not being updated or not being passed out of the User Control. Any solutions?

```
    namespace RowSelection
    {
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<User> users = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<User>()
    {
        new User() { Name = "User 1", Age = 42 },
        new User() { Name = "User 2", Age = 19 },
        new User() { Name = "User 3", Age = 65 },
    };
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = users;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
    public int RowSelection
    {
        get { return _rowSelection; }
        set
        {
            _rowSelection = value;
            lvUsers.SelectedIndex = RowSelection;
            OnPropertyChanged("RowSelection");
        }
    }

    private int _rowSelection;

    private void lvUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RowSelection = lvUsers.SelectedIndex;
        //==============================================================================================================================================
        //This is where the RowSelection property should be set when a row is selected by clicking inside the User Control
        //I know this event is firing but it is not successfully updating the parameter or the parameter value is not being passed outside the control
        //==============================================================================================================================================
    }

    public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<UserControl x:Class="RowSelection.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RowSelection"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid OpacityMask="#FFDECCCC" Background="White" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Margin="5" Name="lvUsers" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a loop in your code. lvUsers.Selection changed, RowSelection changed, lvUsers.Selection changed, and so on.

```
    public int RowSelection
    {
        get { return lvUsers.SelectedIndex; }
        set
        {
             if(lvUsers.SelectedIndex != value)
             {
                 lvUsers.SelectedIndex = value;
             }
        }
     }

     private void lvUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RowSelection));
     }
```

I'm not sure these codes is useful, but you can just try.

Comment: Yeah, I think you were right. I put that change in. But the original issue is sill there. Thanks though!

Comment: You mean you cannot get the selected index out of the UserControl1 class yet? I change the codes, and you can try again.